# Locating roots of a special class of polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$

Tags: polynomials

I am reading Prof. Ram Murty's Prime number and Irreducible polynomials. I am having problem in understanding a part of the following lemma:

**Statement:**
Suppose that $\alpha$ is a complex root of a polynomial
$$
f(x)=x^m+a_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0
$$
with coefficients $a_i$ equal to $0$ or $1$. If $|arg \ \alpha| \le \frac{\pi}{4}$ then $|\alpha| < \frac{3}{2}$. Otherwise $\mathfrak{R}(\alpha) < \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{2}}$.

**Proof:** The cases $m=1$ and $m=2$ can be verified directly. Assuming that $m \ge 3$, we compute for $z \ne 0$:

$$
\left| \frac{f(z)}{z^m}\right| \ge \left| 1+\frac{a_{m-1}}{z}+\frac{a_{m-2}}{z^2}\right| - \left(\frac{1}{|z|^3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{|z|^m}\right).
$$

For $z$ satisfying $|arg \ z| \le \frac{\pi}{4}$ it is true that $\mathfrak{R}(\frac{1}{z^2}) \ge 0$, so for such $z$ we have

$$
\left|\frac{f(z)}{z^m}\right| > 1 - \frac{1}{|z|^2(|z|-1)}
$$

---

1. How to obtain the cases when $m=1,2$?
2. How are the above two inequalities obtained?
3. Where are we using the fact: For $z$ satisfying $|arg \ z| \le \frac{\pi}{4}$ it is true that $\mathfrak{R}(\frac{1}{z^2}) \ge 0$?

Comment: For $m = 1$, the possibilities for the polynomials are $x$ and $x + 1$. The possibilities for $\alpha$ are $0$ and $-1$. Similarly, for $m = 2$, there are only four polynomials and the possible $\alpha$s you can get $0$, $\pm \iota$, $-1$, $\frac{1}{2}(-1 \pm \sqrt{3} \iota)$. You can verify the claim individually for each.

Comment: What do you mean by "the above 2 inequality"? Do you mean both inequalities, or just the second one?

Comment: @PaulSinclair: Sorry for the confusion. I mean both the inequalities. I am making it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof of the first inequality.

$$f(z) = z^m + a_{m-1}z^{m-1} + a_{m-2}z^{m-2} + a_{m-3}z^{m-3}+ \dots+a_0\\
\frac{f(z)}{z^m} = \left(1 + \frac{a_{m-1}}z + \frac{a_{m-2}}{z^2}\right) + \left(\frac{a_{m-3}}{z^3}+ \dots+\frac{a_0}{z^m}\right)\\
\frac{f(z)}{z^m} - \left(\frac{a_{m-3}}{z^3}+ \dots+\frac{a_0}{z^m}\right)= \left(1 + \frac{a_{m-1}}z + \frac{a_{m-2}}{z^2}\right)$$
$$\left|\frac{f(z)}{z^m}\right| + \left(\frac{|a_{m-3}|}{|z|^3}+ \dots+\frac{|a_0|}{|z|^m}\right)\ge \left|1 + \frac{a_{m-1}}z + \frac{a_{m-2}}{z^2}\right|\tag{1}$$
$$\left|\frac{f(z)}{z^m}\right| + \left(\frac{1}{|z|^3}+ \dots+\frac{1}{|z|^m}\right)\ge \left|1 + \frac{a_{m-1}}z + \frac{a_{m-2}}{z^2}\right|\tag{2}\\
\left|\frac{f(z)}{z^m}\right|\ge \left|1 + \frac{a_{m-1}}z + \frac{a_{m-2}}{z^2}\right| -  \left(\frac{1}{|z|^3}+ \dots+\frac{1}{|z|^m}\right)$$
Where $(1)$ is the triangle inequality, and $(2)$ is because $\forall i, |a_i| \le 1$.

[this only works for $|z| > 1$]<s>For the second inequality, note that if $|z| < 1$, then
$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{|z|^3}+ \dots+\frac{1}{|z|^m} &= \frac{1}{|z|^3}\left(1 + |z|^{-1} + \dots+|z|^{-(m-3)}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{|z|^3}\left(\dfrac{1-|z|^{-(m-2)}}{1-|z|^{-1}}\right)\\
&\le\frac{1}{|z|^2(|z|-1)}\end{align}$$
and if $|z| > 1$, then
$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{|z|^3}+ \dots+\frac{1}{|z|^m} &\le \frac{1}{|z|^3}\left(1 + |z|^{-1} + \dots\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{|z|^3}\left(\dfrac1{1-|z|^{-1}}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{|z|^2(|z|-1)}\end{align}$$</s>

So if we can show $\left|1 + \frac{a_{m-1}}z + \frac{a_{m-2}}{z^2}\right| \ge 1$, the inequality you are after follows. This is where $\mathfrak R\left(\frac1{z^2}\right) \ge 0$ comes in. Though not mentioned, the argument restriction also implies $\mathfrak R\left(\frac1{z}\right) \ge 0$. Hence  $$\mathfrak R\left(1 + \frac{a_{m-1}}z + \frac{a_{m-2}}{z^2}\right) \ge 1 + 0 + 0 = 1$$
But the modulus of any number with real part $\ge 1$ must be $\ge 1$ as well. Thus $$\left|1 + \frac{a_{m-1}}z + \frac{a_{m-2}}{z^2}\right| \ge 1$$ as desired.

Comment: I think that $|a_i| \ge 1$. Am I correct?

Comment: No. The $a_i$ are all $0$ or $1$. Note that I also added an explanation for the second inequality. Egglog is correct in why the argument restriction implies $\mathfrak R\left(\frac 1{z^2}\right) \ge 0$.

Comment: Yes yes, you are correct. I am sorry.

Comment: I also just changed the argument for the second inequality a little, as the original argument implicitly assumed $|z| > 1$ to allow the infinite series to converge.

Comment: @Saikat - my proof of the second inequality is flawed. It works fine for $|z| > 1$, but for $|z| < 1$, it does not work. I'll think about it some more.

Comment: Can you please help me understand how do we get $(1)$ from triangle inequality?

Comment: $$|a - b - c| = |a - (b + c)| \le |a| + |-(b+c)| = |a| + |b+c| \le |a| + |b| + |c|$$ and similarly for higher numbers of summands.